# findMany in Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a findMany method in Ember data? I need to manually call it - for example,

```
App.Person.findMany([1, 2, 3]);
```

I keep seeing it in posts/blogs/examples attached to either the store or a model, but it's not coming up in my app.

- If it's implemented, how do I use it?
- If not, can somebody point me in the right direction on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an alias to `findMany`, but you can use the store directly.
Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/sxLf3

```
store.findMany(App.User, [2,3]);
```

Comment: `App.Store = DS.Store.extend({}); App.Store.findMany // undefined`.

Comment: The store is injected by ember, you don't need to create. Do you saw the demo?

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! This is better, because it's also smart about what it requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass something like App.Post.find({ids: [1,2,3]}) which will query:

```
/posts?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3
```

In rails (or insert your server language of choice) you can do something like:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if ids = params[:ids]
      @posts = Post.where(:id => ids)
    else
      @posts = Post.scoped
    end

    respond_with @posts
  end
end
```

There are a few other ways to accomplish this, but as Ember Data can change from time to time this approach tends to not break.

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct answer. That question is related to ember-data and not rails. And not mention "How I fetch many registers in on query using ember-data and rails". Just my opinion.

Comment: This is what worked: `App.Post.find({ids: [1,2,3]})`. Is there another way?

Comment: @CoryLoken, is this smart enough to not fetch if already in store?

Comment: @SamSelikoff this is basically a findQuery which returns an immutable array, so the same find will look at the store, but find 1,2,3,4 would ask for all 4 records. Márcio Rodrigues I showed the rails side as an example of how the server would respond to the query, that could be any other server side language, but I thought an example would be useful.